# ¿ Porque JPA me devuelve los registros relacionados en FETCH LAZY?

Tags: java, postgresql, java-ee, jpa

Estoy usando JPA y estoy teniendo problemas al recuperar registros de tablas que contienen claves foráneas, mi BD es amplia pero simplificare el problema, en una relación típica *REGION -> CIUDAD -> COMUNA*

**Tabla REGION**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
*Primary Key REGION*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tabla CIUDAD**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
*Primary Key CIUDAD*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
*Claves Foráneas CIUDAD*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tabla COMUNA**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
*Primary Key COMUNA*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
*Claves Foráneas COMUNA*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy ejecutando sentencias simples como las siguientes:

```
SELECT r FROM Region r
SELECT c FROM Ciudad c
SELECT c FROM Comuna c
```

Con esas consultas lo que quiero es, en la primera, todos los registros de la tabla *REGION*, en la segunda, todos los registros de la tabla *CIUDAD*, en la tercera, todos los registros de la tabla *COMUNA*. Pero, por ejemplo para la consulta de *COMUNA* estoy obteniendo el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y obtengo resultados muy parecidos para las otras dos consultas, yo no quiero esto, yo quiero, para el ejemplo que planteo, todos los registros de la tabla *COMUNA* sin mas, pero me esta trayendo la relación y ademas que no me esta trayendo todos los registros de la tabla *COMUNA*, solo me esta trayendo el primer registro ("Independencia") y su relaciones, pero esa tabla tiene mas registros.

Estoy utilizando Netbeans para generar el código automáticamente de los Entity Clases, y el Fetch por defecto es LAZY, entiendo que eso esta bien. Estoy utilizando Postgresql, ya he intentado cambiar el LAZY por EAGER en las tablas y el resultado es el mismo.

Por cierto estos ejemplos están basados en Chile, el país se divide en Regiones lo que en otros países son ESTADOS y las Comunas en otros países se les denomina MUNICIPIOS, es solo para meterlos un poco en contexto.

Se que una posible solución es no informarle a la BD las relaciones entre tablas (Las claves foraneas), pero esa no debería ser la solución, es decir no es el DEBER SER.

Acá el código que me solicitaron en los comentarios:

*La implementación del servicio*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Netbeans genera un abstract, este es el abstract*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Estas son las librerías que automáticamente me generan el JSON para salida y entrada al servicio, realmente yo no configure nada de estas librerías, solo las incluí y me funcionan hasta ahora para lo que quiero que es enviar y recibir JSON sin tocarlo*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Aca parte del codigo que genera netbeans, lo demas son getters y setters*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, adjunta el código que te ejecuta la consulta y devuelve ese JSON. Probablemente, estás recorriendo todo el objeto para generar el JSON y, aunque tengas las relaciones como LAZY, te las está recuperando.

Comment: @IvanClavijos agregue lo que me pediste

Comment: como tal vez habrás notado las preguntas que ponen el código como imagen es menos probable que reciban ayuda y casi nunca reciben respuestas con código.

Answer (score 0):

Que marques una relación como LAZY no significa que JPA no vaya a hacer nada con ella cuando recuperas la clase padre. Lo que hace JPA es informar, con una clase proxy especial, el atributo relacionado para que, a efectos de ejecución, sí tenga valor pero hasta que no accedas realmente a él, no se ejecute la consulta que recupera los valores de la relación.

Yendo a tu caso concreto, ese `idRegion`será NULL en aquellos casos en que Comuna no tenga relación con ninguna Region. Cuando esa relación sí exista, el valor de `idRegion` no será una instancia de Region sino una instancia de una clase proxy propia de JPA.

Cuando estás devolviendo la lista de Comunas, el conversor a JSON encuentra que `idRegion`sí tiene valor, por lo que accede a él para serializarlo, momento en que se ejecuta la query y se recuperan los valores.

Para solucionarlo tienes dos opciones:

1. Anotar con `@JsonIgnore`aquellos atributos que son necesarios en tu entidad pero no quieres que se serialicen en la respuesta JSON. Esta solución no es la panacea, porque podría haber casos en que sí quieras recuperar la relación completa, pero eso ya queda fuera esta pregunta
2. Crear una clase DTO (ComunaDTO, por ejemplo) en la que no incluyas la relación con Region y, en tu controlador, en vez de devolver ese `List<Comuna>` que te llega de `super.findAll()`, devuelvas un `List<ComunaDTO>`. Esta solución tampoco es perfecta porque estás creando clases "vacías" que sólo sirven para enviar datos de una capa a otra (modelo anémico). Además, ¿qué pasa si, en vez de sólo los atributos base de Comuna, quieres incluir también el id de la Region?

Comment: el @JsonIgnore donde debo colocarlo ? en el mapeo ? lo coloque en el mapeo de la tabla COMUNA sobre los atributos idCiudad e idRegion y me esta arrojando el mismo resultado.

Comment: Pues le doy una pensada, a ver por qué te está pasando eso. Por cierto, ¿podrías indicar qué import te ha resuelto Netbeans para ese @JsonIgnore?

Comment: import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore;

Comment: Disculpa por tardar... vale, quita ese import y cámbialo por `import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore` y vuelve a probar